# Regex to match string if it's the only thing on the line (except spaces)

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and have done a lot of searching on this but can't fathom it.

I need to match a string (which may contain whitespace), lets say **The Dog**, but only when it is the only item on the line (followed by the \n character). For example, my input file may contain the following, but I am only interested in the first instance of The Dog (it being the only thing on the line is the only way I can distinguish it from potential other instances):

```
The Dog
    property 1 : 5
    property 2 : depends on The Dog
    property 3 : more data
```

Where **The Dog** appears on the line on its own, it may or may not be preceded by whitespace.

I have found similar questions where the answers suggest things such as (^|[ ]), to check for either the beginning of the string or a preceding space, but all the suggestions I have found so far match both instances in my example.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried and also what language's regex you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
^\s*The\s*Dog\s*$
```

See [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lK8eC7/2)

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on the regex flavour you are using, but most of them allow for the `m` flag which ensures that the `^` and `$` tags match for the beginning and end (respectively) of every line. With this, combined with `\s*` to consume any, if at all, whitespace, you can use the following:

```
^\s*The\s*Dog\s*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/C-NKpSBWELJCv3bE)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you could do something like this:

```
var doesMatch = ("  The Dog").match(/^\s*The Dog\s*$/);
if (doesMatch) {
   //found a match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, I used

^\s*The\s*Dog\s*$

Answer (score 0):

Because "The Dog" is only an example according to your original post, I wuld suggest to use `^(?:\s*\w*)+\n`.
This matches a line start, then it matches 1 to an unlimited repetion of zero or unlimited number of whitespace (\s*) followed by zero or an unlimited number of word characters (\w*) followed by a line break.
Because of the `(?:)` the part of the string, that matched won't be captured. This is useful if you only want to test if the string matches. If you want to capture, what part of the string matched, use `^((?:\s*\w*))+\n`.

But as "R Nar" pointed out, it depends on the regex flavour. The above regex would work in javascript, but on in python for example. Tell us in which programming language you try to match the subject string and we can give you a working example.

In case you use javascript, here is how you would loop over all matches capturing the part of the string, that matches:

```
var myregexp = /^((?:\s*\w*)+)\n/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
    // capturing group 1: match[1]
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```